# Graph shortest path infinite cycle

Tags: graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

[image]

So my paint skills are not the best but I think it shows the example well. Imagine I want to calculate the shortest path between A and C, considering all the algorithms I've found are greedy, wouldn't it be stuck in an infinite cycle between A and B?

Any sugestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be an infinite cycle.

Visited and unvisited nodes in the graph are kept track of, and a visited node will never be visited again.

In your example:

1. Mark all nodes as unvisited, except for the starting node which is visited
2. Starting with A, visit B, mark B as visited
3. B can only visit A or C, but A has already been marked as visited
4. The only available node is C, which is unvisited

Comment: Make sure you repeat process for each node as a starting node if you are trying to get a list of all shortest paths.

Comment: @rob Oh ok, that makes sense! Thank you. So I could use Dijkstra here, right?

Comment: Yes, you could use Dijkstra's algorithm here.

Comment: @rob sorry to keep bothering you, but how would you calculate the shortest path between A and F here http://i.imgur.com/iHObkLo.png ? Because I've ran into a stalemate when going C from E, because I can't go back to E...

Answer (score 0):

I usually put into each node the distance and path (list of nodes) from starting point.  When I enter a node I compare current distance against existing distance.  if the current distance is shorter than existing, I replace the new path with old path.

Another method is to keep a list of distances at each node to every other node.  Fill in this list as you leave each node.

Start at A : Set A already visited.  Go to B.  Then back to A.  A is already visited so at B add distance from B To A as 26.
Move from B to D.  Then back to B.  B already visited so at D add distance D to B as 96.  Add distance from D to A as 96 + 26 = 112.
Move from D to E.  Then back to D.  D already visited so at E add distance E to D as 21.  Add distance from E to B as 21 + 96 = 117.  Add distance E to A as 21 + 96 + 26 = 143.